# how to use Octuple precision in python

Tags: python, floating-point

I have come across this problem to check if a number is divisible by 5 or not.

one of many solutions which i have done is

```
def f(x):
     return x/5==x//5
```

this is running fine, up to 2^53-1 or 10^17 digits value. above that it is giving me error.

i find it it is due to floatig point error . 
[IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats)

in the link , it's given that there is binary256( octuple precision).

didn't find anything helpful to implement this in python.

ps. i don't need a solution to check a number is divisible by 5 or not.

Comment: Even if you throw more precision at the problem, this approach is still wrong. Also, it's hard to find support for even quadruple precision, let alone octuple. The fact that you're jumping straight for octuple precision is a warning sign that you're thinking about precision wrong.

Comment: i know this approach is wrong, here i '/' is taking binary precision , my point is is there a way through which we can change this default precision taken by '/'

Comment: Trying to throw more floating-point precision at this particular problem is like trying to buy a bigger gun to shoot yourself in the foot with. Do you have a problem that more precision would actually solve? There are plenty of more precise options, from `numpy.longdouble` to `decimal.Decimal` to `fractions.Fraction` to `gmpy2` to reformulating your calculations to operate in integer arithmetic, but what option to pick depends on the problem you need to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Default precision" implies you could select a different precision. You cannot.

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html:

> numbers.Real (float)
>
> These represent machine-level double precision
> floating point numbers. **You are at the mercy of the underlying machine
> architecture (and C or Java implementation) for the accepted range and
> handling of overflow.** Python does not support single-precision
> floating point numbers; the savings in processor and memory usage that
> are usually the reason for using these are dwarfed by the overhead of
> using objects in Python, so there is no reason to complicate the
> language with two kinds of floating point numbers.

There is no guarantee that you even *have* IEEE 754 floating-point values.